Why wont the ball move around and why does the pygame screen crash when I run it?
import pygame
from sys import exit

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 600))
running = True

ball_moving = True
ball_speed = 100
ballX = 500
ballY = 300


while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit
            exit()

    while ball_moving:
        ballX += ball_speed
        ballY += ball_speed
        if ballX == 1000:
            ballX -= ball_speed
        if ballY == 600:
            ballY -= ball_speed
        if ballX == 0:
            ballX += ball_speed
        if ballY == 0:
            ballY += ball_speed
        ball = pygame.draw.circle(screen, "White", center = (ballX, ballY), radius = 35, width = 35)


    pygame.display.update()

The
while ball_moving:
        ballX += ball_speed
        ballY += ball_speed
        if ballX == 1000:
            ballX -= ball_speed
        if ballY == 600:
            ballY -= ball_speed
        if ballX == 0:
            ballX += ball_speed
        if ballY == 0:
            ballY += ball_speed


part wont run when I start the program. If I remove it, it works fine. I'm trying to make the ball object bounce around the screen.
I tried to remove the while loop and use others methods but the program just crashes.

Try if ball_moving: instead. The problem is that if you make that a loop, then the loop never ends and you never reach the "update" part.

You never change ball_moving, so that loop will never end.  What were you expecting?  Did you mean if?

Beware of your bounds tests. They are using equality testing, but if you change ball_speed such that the ball doesn't end on an exact boundary, it will never bounce. Use >= and <= instead.

You're using two loops, which makes it impossible to execute pygame.display.update().
To fix it, try this.
import pygame
from sys import exit

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 600))
running = True

ball_moving = True
ball_speed = 100
ballX = 500
ballY = 300


while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit
            exit()

    ballX += ball_speed
    ballY += ball_speed
    if ballX == 1000:
        ballX -= ball_speed
    if ballY == 600:
        ballY -= ball_speed
    if ballX == 0:
        ballX += ball_speed
    if ballY == 0:
        ballY += ball_speed
    ball = pygame.draw.circle(screen, "White", center = (ballX, ballY), radius = 35, width = 35)


    pygame.display.update()


You say "try this", but they mention in the question that they already tried that. It's not what they want.

@paddy Yes, but I've changed the problematic part (while ball_moving:)
